# vim status bar not consistent in all file

Tags: vimrc, filetype, statusline

I recently set my vim status bar using this:

```
" set status line
set laststatus=2
set statusline=
set statusline+=%#StatusLineFile#
set statusline+=\ %F
set statusline+=%m
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=%#StatusLineTail#
set statusline+=\ %y
set statusline+=\ %{&fileencoding?&fileencoding:&encoding}
set statusline+=\[%{&fileformat}\]
set statusline+=\ %p%%
set statusline+=\ %l:%c
set statusline+=\
```

in `~/.vimrc`, it works well most of the time, but some times it does not work and shows the default status bar (white background and black text), here is the img:
[image]
as you can see, the latex log is using the default status bar instead of that in `.vimrc`, how can I fix the problem so that it is consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "quickfix window". Read `:h quickfix.txt` to get more info on it.

To disable quickfix custom status line you have to execute `let g:qf_disable_statusline = 1` before opening it for the first time (or put this line into your vimrc, obviously).

Still remember that your "generic" status line may have a lesser value when applied to special windows/buffers.